# Best Online Course for Learning Quant Trading?

Tags: learning

I've read through most of the intro resources on Quantopian, but I was wondering if anyone here has recommendations for online courses that focus on Quant Trading? I found one class called [Algorithmic Trading Strategies](https://www.experfy.com/training/courses/algorithmic-trading-strategies) on Experfy that seems like the best option right now. Has anyone taken this class before?

Comment: A very warm welcome to Quant.SE and thank you for your question - pls. see my answer below: https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/34785/12

Comment: Imho, you cannot learn quant trading in a course. But you can start learning the requirements for it in a course. Be aware that most of the time you will still have no knowledge about the assets you want to trade at all. You should spend considerable time on that too!

Comment: If the answers given were helpful please upvote them and please accept one of them - this community is built on feedback! Thank you

Answer (score 9):

Although not free, [DataCamp](https://www.datacamp.com/home) has a very good reputation: they have a whole career track "Quantitative Analyst" with 12 courses altogether:

> [Quantitative Analyst with R](https://www.datacamp.com/tracks/quantitative-analyst-with-r)
>  In finance, quantitative analysts
>   ensure portfolios are risk balanced, help find new trading
>   opportunities, and evaluate asset prices using mathematical models.

One of the courses is called "[Financial Trading in R](https://www.datacamp.com/courses/financial-trading-in-r)"

I have taken some of DataCamp's courses myself (e.g. machine learning for R and Python) and would in general recommend it. I also use it as part of my teaching R in my data sciences classes at my university.

Comment: I haven't had this particular course, but I will also highly recommend DataCamp.

Comment: @vonjd Hello. What do you think of the masters in financial engineering program offered by WorldQuant University

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you want to do with your knowledge after completing a course and your background. Do you want to end up with a degree and hence improve your future career opportunities (get a job in a hedge fund) or do you want to jump start and trade on your own? For the latter I would suggest The Python Quants: http://training.tpq.io/algo_brochure.pdf If you want to take it all the way, then consider taking a masters degree over two years at WorldQuant University: https://wqu.org/